# Drupal 6 term based view not translating vocabulary terms

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a dilly of a pickle here. Please do help if you can.

I have a site that uses internationalization translation to translate content.
Some of the content is not translating.
Specifically a "view" that is of type "term".  All my other views are translating correctly.

Here is the configuration page of my vocabulary
[image]

Here is an example of the term translations.
[image]

Here is the view for the taxonomy term countries.
The view here seems to not have the correct  filters available. For node based views, you can add a filter called "node translation-language" and set it to filter on the current language.  But with views based on taxonomies there is no equivalent "term translation-language".  How are we supposed to filter out the extra taxonomy terms from the view.

[image]

This is an example of a view based on nodes that has the filter "term translation-language"
My term based view is missing this filter
[image]

Here is the Countries view in action...notice that Haiti shows up for every language in it's non translated form (note that those are 3 different Haiti's)

[image]

Can someone please explain what I need to do to get a term based view translating and not showing extra terms?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you are trying to do is something along these lines:

[image]

Which here gives me:

[image]

And when I change the language, eg:

[image]

it then gives me:

[image]

I've set my vocabulary here up like so:

[image]

with translations (quickly done just for this so pardon the potential sloppiness)

[image]

and nodes translated like this (pardon the silly titles):

[image]

[image]

so if you are getting different results, check to make sure all of the various places you can set a language are similar.